# Magento Slow Category Count Query

Tags: mysql, sql, magento, magento-1.9, query-performance

We have recently deployed some changes to our Magento store, which has triggered the following SQL to be run:

```
SELECT `count_table`.`category_id`, COUNT(DISTINCT count_table.product_id) AS `product_count` 

FROM `catalog_product_flat_1` AS `e`

INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND 1

INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0

INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_eav` AS `brand_idx` ON brand_idx.entity_id = e.entity_id AND brand_idx.attribute_id = '135' AND brand_idx.store_id = 1 AND brand_idx.value IN('967')

INNER JOIN `catalog_product_flat_1` ON catalog_product_flat_1.entity_id=e.entity_id

INNER JOIN `catalog_product_flat_1` AS `catalog_product_flat_1_2` ON catalog_product_flat_1.entity_id=e.entity_id

INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `count_table` ON count_table.product_id = e.entity_id 

WHERE (e.status = 1) AND (catalog_product_flat_1.brand = '967') AND (catalog_product_flat_1.brand = '967') AND (count_table.store_id = 1) AND (count_table.category_id IN ('335', '334', '332', '339', '337', '943')) 

GROUP BY `count_table`.`category_id`;
```

This SQL takes a couple of seconds to run and if a number of users hit the same page at once, the server will eventually grind to a halt as the queries back up.

Running an `EXPLAIN` provides this:

```
1   SIMPLE  brand_idx   ref PRIMARY,IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_INDEX_EAV_ENTITY_ID,IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_INDEX_EAV_ATTRIBUTE_ID,IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_INDEX_EAV_STORE_ID,IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_INDEX_EAV_VALUE   IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_INDEX_EAV_VALUE 4   const   17  Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  count_table ref PRIMARY,IDX_CAT_CTGR_PRD_IDX_PRD_ID_STORE_ID_CTGR_ID_VISIBILITY,15D3C269665C74C2219037D534F4B0DC    IDX_CAT_CTGR_PRD_IDX_PRD_ID_STORE_ID_CTGR_ID_VISIBILITY 6   db.brand_idx.entity_id,const    1   Using where; Using index
1   SIMPLE  e   eq_ref  PRIMARY,IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_FLAT_1_STATUS   PRIMARY 4   db.brand_idx.entity_id  1   Using where
1   SIMPLE  cat_index   ref IDX_CAT_CTGR_PRD_IDX_PRD_ID_STORE_ID_CTGR_ID_VISIBILITY,15D3C269665C74C2219037D534F4B0DC    IDX_CAT_CTGR_PRD_IDX_PRD_ID_STORE_ID_CTGR_ID_VISIBILITY 6   db.brand_idx.entity_id,const    1   Using where; Using index
1   SIMPLE  catalog_product_flat_1  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   db.brand_idx.entity_id  1   Using where
1   SIMPLE  price_index eq_ref  PRIMARY,IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_INDEX_PRICE_CUSTOMER_GROUP_ID,IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_INDEX_PRICE_WEBSITE_ID,IDX_CAT_PRD_IDX_PRICE_WS_ID_CSTR_GROUP_ID_MIN_PRICE    PRIMARY 8   db.brand_idx.entity_id,const,const  1   Using index
1   SIMPLE  catalog_product_flat_1_2    index   NULL    IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_FLAT_1_ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID 2   NULL    21529   Using index; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join)
```

Which, to me, suggests that there is a missing index somewhere, based on the `brand_idx` table using `Using temporary; Using filesort`. But is that true?

If it is, how do I identify the missing index and, secondly, how would I apply this index in Magento?

I know it's also related to selecting `COUNT(DISTINCT count_table.product_id)` and grouping by `count_table`.`category_id` as removing either of these parts results in a quicker query (just without the information that's expected!).

Comment: The filesort is probably for the `group by`.  There's not much you can do to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is a result of the two `inner join`'s that reference the same table, `catalog_product_flat_1`, but the join condition on the second instance of the join references the table from the first:

```
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_flat_1` ON catalog_product_flat_1.entity_id=e.entity_id

INNER JOIN `catalog_product_flat_1` AS `catalog_product_flat_1_2` ON **catalog_product_flat_1**.entity_id=e.entity_id
```

Although the question references Magento, this is actually to do with Zend_Db and the way you define the joins.

Given a Zend_Db_Select object, you can create a join like so:

```
$select->joinInner('catalog_product_flat_1', 'catalog_product_flat_1.entity_id = e.entity_id');
```

This is ok the first time you do it, but if you were to do it a second time, the `joinInner` function will intelligently identify a second join on the `catalog_product_flat_1` table and call it `catalog_product_flat_1_2`, but the issue occurs because it does not identify the incorrect table alias in the join condition.

The way to resolve this is to explicitly set the table alias name by providing a name correlation, like so:

```
$select->joinInner(array('unique_table_alias' => 'catalog_product_flat_1'), 'unique_table_alias.entity_id = e.entity_id');
```

With the second join referencing the correct table alias, the query time was reduced from `3s` to `20ms`.

The fact that Magento is adding the inner joins twice is another matter, but once configured correctly, doesn't affect performance.

Comment: I am looking something else here, but your explanation help me a bit to solve my problem